# Why does Visual C++ 2008 not complain when I (accidentally) use type boolean

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have been doing some Java work and so mistakenly in a cpp file created a function like this:

```
inline boolean is_whatever() const { return type_ == whatever; }
```

And it compiled just fine.

Then when I compiled the same code on UNIX it failed with:

```
error: `boolean' does not name a type
```

Why doesn't VS complain?

Is there a flag that I can set to prevent this laxity?

Comment: Apparently there is a `typedef unsigned char boolean` in rpcndr.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just so happens that `boolean` has been defined in some other header that you have included (directly or indirectly). For instance if you include `windows.h` then that pulls in many other headers, some of which have this:

```
typedef unsigned char boolean;
```

If any of those headers are included in your cpp file then `boolean` becomes part of the namespace.  If this was to be 'fixed' in the Windows API then thousands of legacy projects would no longer compile and developers would be up in arms.  It's use probably dates back to before `bool` was a concrete type in C++ (bear in mind too that the Windows API is C, rather than C++)

Answer (score 1):

Use bool instead of boolean, the you will avoid such inconveniences.

Comment: Thanks for stating the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

`boolean` is not a C++ type. Maybe there is a `typedef bool boolean` somewhere, but it's not a built-in type.

Use `bool` instead.